# OMAP4 Camera Parameters

Tags: android, compilation, camera, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, hal

IM trying to enter The Default OMAP 4 Camera Parameters in CameraParameters found here http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/hardware-ti-omap4xxx/camera/CameraParameters.cpp

```
const char CameraProperties::CAMERA_NAME[]="prop-camera-name";
const char CameraProperties::CAMERA_SENSOR_INDEX[]="prop-sensor-index";
const char CameraProperties::CAMERA_SENSOR_ID[] = "prop-sensor-id";
```

Not to sure how i should enter these

eg like this

```
const char CameraProperties::CAMERA_SENSOR_INDEX[2]="prop-sensor-index";
```

or

```
const char CameraProperties::CAMERA_SENSOR_INDEX[]="prop-sensor-index,2";
```

or

const char CameraProperties::CAMERA_SENSOR_INDEX[]="prop-sensor-index"{2};

Logcat of original looks like this

> CameraHal [D] (1ccbs18)
>   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraParameters.cpp:202 dump -
>   prop-sensor-index = 2